# Help with counting problems

Tags: combinatorics

So this is the question i am having problem with:

1) in how many ways can the letter a,b,c,d,e,f be arranged so that the letter a and b are next to each other, but a and c are not. i know that if a and b are together then there is 5!*2=240 possible combinations, but how do i go from there to find how many of those will not have a and c together. i can see that we have ab then c should be to the left or if we have ba then c should be to the right so i came up with idea of finding how many combos can we have with CAB and BAC and got 3!*4*2=48, so answer should be 240-48=192, is this right?

2)In how many ways can the letters a, b, c, d, e, f be arranged so that a is not next to b or c?

for this i found first total number of possible combinations which is 6!=720, then i looked at how many combos we could have if we  had

ab _ _ _ _ this is a to the left of b but not next to c, so 4!=24, note ab always stays at the start i am not shuffling it

_ _ _ _ ba this is a to the right of b but not next to c, so 4!=24 note ba always stays at the end i am not shuffling it

cab _ _ _ this case cover if a is between a and c so we have either cab or bac, so i get 4!*2=48

so 720-24-24-48=624, am i right on this one?

3) In how many ways can the letters a, b, c, d, e, f be arranged so that a is not next to b, c, d, or e?

for this one i realized that the only possible way it can happen is if we have

af _ _ _ _ or _ _ _ _ fa and a cant be anywhere in the middle for af case we get 4!=24 and for fa case we get 4!=24 so there is 48 possible ways. is this right?

Comment: Hint: Use complements.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  For 1, now that you have computed the number with $ab$ together, you just need to subtract the number with $cab$ or $bac$ in those specific orders.  You use the same technique you just used to get that.

For 2, if $a$ is on an end, select the next letter in (how many) ways, then order the rest.  If $a$ is not on an end, select the two neighboring letters, then order the rest.

For 3, if $a$ is not on one end, you are dead.  So you have $af$ at the start or $fa$ at the end.